# Gateaux and Frechet derivatives and boundedness

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis

Suppose $f:X \to Y$ is map between Banach spaces.

We know that the Frechet derivative of $f$ at $x$ is a **bounded** map by definition if it exists (satisfying certain properties that I won't write) $f'(x):X \to Y$.

We also know that if one can show that the Gateaux derivative of $f$ at $x$, $DF(x):X \to Y$ is continuous at $x$, then the Frechet derivative at $x$ exists and is given by the Gateaux derivative at $x$.

I don't think that the Gateaux derivative of any function is required to be bounded. I am reading the free book Applied Analysis by Hunter and it doesn't say anything, but I am not sure.

So my question is, if I find the Gateaux derivative of a function at $x$ and show that it is continuous at $x$ **without** showing that it is bounded (i.e., $\lVert DF(x)h\rVert \leq C\lVert h\rVert$), can I still use the theorem to say that the Frechet derivative exists and hence is bounded? It seems wrong to say so.

By what I wrote above, the answer should be yes. But I have seen a lot of conflicting statements about Gateaux derivatives so I'm not sure.

Comment: Be careful: the Fréchet derivative is a *linear* map. For many authors, the Gateaux derivative is not necessarily linear. Others say that $\varphi$ is G-differentiable at $u$ if there exists a *linear and continuous* map $f$ such that $\frac{d}{dt}\varphi(u+tv)\Big|_{t=0}=\langle f,v \rangle$ for every $v$.

Comment: M. Berger, in his *Nonlinearity and functional analysis*, says that "if the Gateaux derivative is linear and continuous, then the Fréchet derivative exists and coincides with the G-derivative". Also Wikipedia shows the G-derivatives are often defined in different ways, in the literature. However, remember that the space of *all* linear mappings is hardly turned into a Banach space, if you forget boundedness; it becomes harder to define continuity for G-derivatives.

Comment: @Siminore In the specific case I'm working on, the G-derivative is linear and I can show it's continuous. So I guess I should read the proof of the theorem and see if boundedness is used anywhere..

Comment: Looks like I do need boundedness.

Comment: It doesn't come as a surprise: you need a uniform estimate but you start from an estimate on straight lines. It is reasonable that you  need some continuity.

Comment: [was discussed here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/145910/gateaux-derivative/)

Comment: If you have an expression for the Gateaux derivative wouldn't it be easy to check if it is bounded?