# When does Gâteaux imply Fréchet?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, banach-spaces

Speaking of the relation between Gâteaux and Fréchet, authors usually point out that $$\text{Fréchet} \implies \text{Gâteaux}$$
and then give a counterexample to illustrate that the converse doesn't hold.

Say, we have a function which is known to be Gâteaux differentiable (all directional derivatives exist). I wonder what conditions need to be added in order to insure Fréchet differentiability?

In case the function goes from $\mathbb R^n$, the continuity of partial derivatives does the job. But what if the function is between two Banach spaces? Would it suffice if all directional derivatives are continuous?

**Update**: I have found the following theorem, unfortunately without any proof.

> Let $X,Y$ be Banach spaces and $U\subset X$ open. If the following conditions hold:
>
> - $f:U\to Y$ has continuous Gâteaux derivative \begin{align} 
>   df: U \times X & \to Y
>   \\ (x,h) & \mapsto df(x,h)
>   \end{align}
> - the linear operator $df(x,\cdot)$ is bounded for all $x\in U$
> - the function \begin{align}U & \to \mathcal{L}(X,Y)
>   \\ x & \mapsto df(x,\cdot)
>   \end{align} is continuous
>
> then $f\in C^1(U,Y)$.

Does it look reasonable? Where could I find the proof?

Comment: You can view [these excellent answers](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/145910/gateaux-derivative/) (especially the longest one, who gives you every kind of references) Obviuosly all credits go to the authors of the answers linked above :)