# Calculation of a Frechet derivative

Tags: calculus, analysis, functional-analysis, derivatives, calculus-of-variations

Say I have an infinite sequence $X=(x_i)$, $i=1,2,3,\ldots$ such that it's in $\ell^2$ space, i.e. $\sum_{i=1}^\infty|x_i|^2<\infty$.  Now, this function that takes this infinite sequence to a real number:

$$\tag{1}F(X)=\sum_{i=1}^\infty\ln \left(1+\frac{x_i}{a_i}\right)$$

(let's assume that $x_i\geq0$ for all $i$ and (1) converges).

What can I say about the Frechet derivative at $X$?  Does the fact that $\frac{\partial F}{\partial x_i}=\frac{1}{a_i+x_i}$ exist for every $i$ tell me anything?  How do I compute it here?

Comment: You have a candidate for the Gâteaux derivative of $F$. Show that it is indeed it, this is a matter of one-variable limit. Then use the fact that a Gâteaux derivative that is continuous with respect to the base point is in fact a Fréchet derivative: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/145910

Comment: @NormalHuman Thanks for the comment!  So, Gateaux derivative at $X$ in the direction $\psi=(y_i), i=1,2,3,\ldots$ is $dF(X,\psi)=\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{y_i}{a_i+x_i}$.  However, I am not sure how to show that this is continuous, and what continuity here even means.  The wikipedia article on Gateaux derivative (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%A2teaux_derivative) is rather confusing. Could you please clarify?