# Different definitions of the continuity of the Gâteaux-Derivative are inequivalent in Banach spaces

Tags: continuity, banach-spaces, gateaux-derivative, frechet-derivative

I am wondering about a problem from the calculus of derivatives in Banachspaces.
It is about the difference between two definitions of continuity concerning the Gâteaux-Derivative of a function $P:X\rightarrow Y$ in Banach spaces $X,Y$.The Gâteaux-Derivative in $f$ in direction $h$ is then defined as: 
\begin{align}
  DP(f)h=lim_{t \rightarrow 0}[P(f+th)-P(f)]/t
\end{align}
There are now two different ways in defining the continuity of $DP$. The first way is that $DP$ as a function in the two variables $f$ and $h$ is continuous on the Product-Space:
\begin{equation}
DP:(U\subset X)\times X \rightarrow Y \ \ \ \ \ (1)
\end{equation}
is continuous. 
The second way is two consider $DP$ as a map from the Banach space $X$ or better a subset $U \subset X$ to the space $L(X,Y)$ of the linear functionals from $X$ to $Y$:
\begin{equation}
DP:U\rightarrow L(X,Y) \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (2)
\end{equation}
is continuous. The question now is if these two definitions are equivalent in the case of Banach spaces. In the case of Fréchet-Spaces $X,Y$ its  obviously not equivalent because in general $L(X;Y)$ is not a Fréchet-Space anymore, its not metrizable in general . But what about the Banach spaces? Is it equivalent in this case? 
What we know is that when $P$ is Gâteaux-differentiable and $DP$ continuous,in the sense of continuity on product spaces, then $P$ is also Fréchet-differentiable and the Fréchet-Derivative is the same as the Gâteaux-Derivative. As discussed for example in [Gâteaux derivative](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/145910/g%c3%a2teaux-derivative). But is it also continuous in the sense of continuity of Fréchet-Derivatives, continuous as a map described in (2). Does anybody maybe know a counterexample?

I think that an example for a function, gateux-differentiable and continous in the first sense on the product space $U\times Y$, but not continuous as a function $U\rightarrow L(X,Y)$ should be the function $P:L^{1}([0,\pi])\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by \begin{equation} f\rightarrow \int\limits_{0}^{\pi} \sin(f(t))dt \end{equation} This function is described in, http://www.m-hikari.com/ams/ams-password-2009/ams-password17-20-2009/gaxiolaAMS17-20-2009.pdf,  where it is shown that $P$ is gateux-differentiable but not frechet-differentiable. It is not continuous in the second sense, which one can easily see by testing with functions centered on a small Intervall with values $n \in \mathbf{N}$. But it should be continuous on the product space $U\times X$.

Comment: Just quick comment: it shouldn't be; because directional derivatives does not imply continuity of derivative or even the existence of the latter: consider $f(\xi_1, \xi_2) = \dfrac{\xi_1 \xi_2}{\xi_1^4 + \xi_2^2}.$ Unless I quite didn't get your question, the existence of derivative implies the existence of directional derivatives; if the former is continuous (as a function), the latters are also continuous (sum of compositions by inclusions and projections). But maybe I am missing something.

Comment: There is something odd in this statement: " What we know is that when $P$ is Gâteaux-differentiable and $DP$ continuous,in the sense of continuity on product spaces, then $P$ is also Fréchet-differentiable and the Fréchet-Derivative is the same as the Gâteaux-Derivative"

If $f$ is defined in the product of Banach spaces, then the existence of partials _everywhere_ in some ball and continuity in the centre of the ball imply the existence of the the derivative.

Comment: I am writing a book in the topic of differential calculus (in normed vector spaces, either complete or not) and I provide an example of a function whose partials exist and are continuous and fail to be differentiable. The example is $f(\xi_1, \xi_2) = \xi_1^{\frac{2}{3}}$ for $\xi_1 = \xi_2 \geq 0$ and $f(\xi_1, \xi_2) = 0$ elsewhere. Partials exist on the set $\xi_1 \neq \xi_2$ and at $(0,0),$ are continuous at $(0,0)$ but $f$ is not differentiable.

Comment: You are quite right that this is odd . If $P$ is gateux-differentiable, then we need $DP$ to be continuous as a function \begin{equation} DP:U\rightarrow L(X,Y)\end{equation}. See for example(Prop. 3.2.15 in Drabek--Milota);