# Example of a C^n Gateaux differentiable function which is not Frechet differentiable

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $P:U\subset (B_1,\| \cdot\|_{B_1}) \to (B_2,\|\cdot \|)$ be a continuous map between Banach spaces over $\mathbb{R}$. And consider the following two notions of derivative:

$\textbf{Gateaux derivative:}$ Define the directional derivative at $x\in U$ in the direction of $h\in B_1 $ by
$$ DP(x)h:= \underset{t\to 0}{\mathrm{lim}}\  \frac{P(x+th)-P(h)}{t}.$$
We call $P$ differentiable at $x\in U$ in the direction $h\in B_1$ if $DP(x)h$ exists and we say $P$ is $C^1-G$ if $DP(x)h$ exists for all $x\in U$ and $h\in B_1$ and if
$$ DP:U\times B_1\to B_2$$
is continuous. Similarly, we define for $x\in U$ and $h_1,\dots,h_n\in B_1$ the limit
$$ D^nP(x)\{h_1, \dots , h_n\}:= \underset{t\to 0}{\mathrm{lim}}\  \frac{D^{n-1}P(x+th_n)\{h_1,\dots ,h_{n-1}\}-P(x)\{h_1,\dots,h_{n-1}\}}{t}$$
and we say $P$ is $C^n-G$ if $D^nP$ exists and is continuous as a map
$$ D^nP:U\times B_1^n\to B_2.$$
Note that this definition holds on more general topological vector spaces $B_1$ and $B_2$. However, for the question this is sufficient.

$\textbf{Frechet derivative:}$ We call $P$ Frechet differentiable at $x\in U$ if there exists a bounded linear operator $A\in \mathcal{L}(B_1,B_2)$ such that
$$ \underset{\|h\|\to 0}{\mathrm{lim}}\  \frac{\|P(x+h)-P(x)-Ah\|}{\|h\|}=0.$$
If such a operator $A$ exists it is unique and we write $\tilde{D}P(x)=A$. We say $P$ is $C^1-F$ if the map
$$ \tilde{D}P:U\to \mathcal{L}(B_1,B_2)$$
is continuous.

$\textbf{Questions:}$ It is well known, (see multiple posts here, etc.) that being Gateaux differentiable is weaker than being Frechet differentiable.  The question is to what extend does this hold:

1. Is there an example of an operator $P$ which is $C^1-G$ such that $\tilde{D}P$ does not exist at some points? Can $P$ even be $C^n-G$?
2. What is an example of a $P$ which is $C^1-G$ but not $C^1-F$?
3. Are there examples for which $P$ is $C^n-G$ for some $n>1$ but not $C^1-F$?

This is very much related to this post:
[Fréchet differentiability from Gâteaux differentiability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/145910/fr%C3%A9chet-differentiability-from-g%C3%A2teaux-differentiability)

The following example gives an indication what could happen. It is Example I.1.3.1 in Hamilton's paper:
https://projecteuclid.org/journals/bulletin-of-the-american-mathematical-society-new-series/volume-7/issue-1/The-inverse-function-theorem-of-Nash-and-Moser/bams/1183549049.full

Consider the operator
$$L:\mathbb{R}\times C_{2\pi}^0(\mathbb{R})\to C_{2\pi}^0(\mathbb{R}), \qquad (t,f)\mapsto L(t,f): x\to f(t+x) $$
where $C_{2\pi}^0(\mathbb{R})$ denotes the space of continuous $2\pi$ periodic functions.

Then $L$ is continuous, but the map
$$L:\mathbb{R} \to \mathcal{L}(C_{2\pi}^0(\mathbb{R}),C_{2\pi}^0(\mathbb{R})), \qquad t\mapsto L(t,\cdot)$$
is not continuous.